# jQuery special event API

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm creating a special event as described in article by [Brandon Aaron here](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/03/26/special-events)
This event needs to trigger on window resize.

```
$.event.special.myevent = {
setup: function () {
    $(window).bind("resize", $.event.special.myevent.handler);
},

teardown: function () {
    $(window).unbind("resize", $.event.special.myevent.handler);
},

handler: function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    //some other rulles

    console.log("handler function");

    e.type = "myevent";

    jQuery.event.handle.apply(this, arguments);
}

}
```

binding to event:

```
$("#myDiv1").bind("myevent", function () {
    alert("my event sub");
})
```

Problem:
`$("#myDiv1")` doesn't receive the event. This seem to be related to the fact that in setup I trigger on `$(window)` instead of `$(this)`.

Question is how can I have the event that piggybacks on events happening on other objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to change the `this` reference inside the function:

```
setup: function () {
    $(window).on("resize.myevent", $.proxy($.event.special.myevent.handler, this));
},

teardown: function () {
    $(window).off("resize.myevent");
},
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7BLvQ/2/)

I've used an event namespace for removing the handler more easily, so you don't need a reference to the function generated by `$.proxy`.